# Two sql if statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run through two `IF` statements in sql. The IF's are two different conditions, example:

```
IF (@user == 'Bob')
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM table Where id = 1
END
IF (@animal == 'Cat')
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 50
END
```

What i want back are rows 1 if only the first condition is correct or 1 and 50 if both conditions are met.
This fails at the second `IF` statement, is there another keyword I need to add?

Comment: What does "fails" mean?

Comment: Do you need them in one resultset?

Comment: Be aware that a batch/command/stored procedure can return multiple result sets. Each select statement will correspond to a result set. The way that your SQL is written, you will have at most 2 separate result sets, both containing either zero or one record. Is that what you want, or do you want the results in some other form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend a single statement:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM table
WHERE
    (@user = 'Bob' AND Id = 1)
    OR
    (@animal= 'Cat' AND Id = 50)
```

Comment: ID has to be a result, not a selection value.

Comment: @Martin . . . Can you elaborate?  Based on my reading of the question, this simplifies the logic and does what the OP wants.

Comment: @Gordon, the OP wants ID to be 50 if `user = 'Bob' AND Animal = 'Cat'` and ID to 1 if `User = 'Bob'`. This query does not do that. Based on his question i would suggest `ELSE IF` instead of two `IF's`.

Comment: @Martin, check the OP query, he's doing a SELECT * FROM table where id = 1

Comment: @Tamim, Don't look at the code in OP, because that is wrong. That's why he asked us. Read the question carefully.

Comment: @Martin, I think the code gives a notion of the guys has in mind, anyways, my answer is here, if any SO user likes it, they can use it.

Comment: @TamimSalem I think the OP has to rewrite his question. You can read it in several ways.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear but this is what i wanted, thanks very much

Comment: @Lloyd The question states "rows 1 if only the first condition is correct or 1 and 50 if both conditions are met". So if `@user = 'John'` and `@animal = 'Cat'`, do you want to only get the record with id 50, or do you want to get no records? This answer gives the former. If you want the latter, then you would need to adjust the conditions in the where condition slightly.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF (@user == 'Bob')
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM table Where id = 1
END
ELSE IF (@animal == 'Cat') and (@user == 'Bob')
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 50
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF (@user = 'Bob')
BEGIN
    IF (@animal = 'Cat')
    BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 50
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN   
       SELECT * FROM table Where id = 1
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for what you want.

```
  SELECT * FROM table Where id = 1 && @user == 'Bob'

Union

  SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 50 && @animal == 'Cat' && @user == 'Bob'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this nested if function:

```
SELECT * FROM table Where id = IF(@user=='Bob',1,IF(@animal=='Cat',50));
```

Comment: sql server uses a different syntax

Comment: Could of just noted that, but hey, that's what the internet is for.